# How to store an object in component's state?

Tags: reactjs

I make an Ajax request that returns me an object like this :

```
Object { user1: "darkblue", user2: "darkred" }
```

How can I store this object in the component's state since none of the following works :

```
this.state = { usersColors: '' } // use for strings
this.state = { usersColors: [] } // used for arrays
```

Which syntax use for storing objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialise any variable as `object`, write it like this:

```
this.state = { usersColors: {} }
```

And use `setState` to update the state once you get the response, like this:

```
this.setState({usersColors: response})
```

Now you can access the response values by:

```
this.state.usersColors.user1   ---->   "darkblue"

this.state.usersColors.user2   ---->   "darkred"
```

**Update:**

Check this snippet:

```js
let state = {
   userColors: {
      user1: 'red',
      user2: 'blue'
   }
}

let username = 'user1';

console.log('user1 value = ', state.userColors[username]);
```

Comment: thanks you. Just one last thing please, if "user1" was stored in a variable 'username'. How can I retrieve the color of user1?

Comment: @Mit didn't get you, *"user1 was stored in a variable username"* means inside state variable userColors contains another variable `username` inside that you are storing the `user1` value, then in that case: `this.state.userColors.username.user1`, if you directly storing the `user1` value inside `username` then: `this.state.username.user1`

Comment: No there is no `usersColors.username.user1` possible here, just `usersColors.user1` to access to "darkblue". But if my string "user1" was stored in a variable "username". How could I access the darkblue through the variable username?

Comment: in that case use `[]` to access the `object` value by a variable, like this: `this.state.userColors[username]`, whatever we write inside `[]` will get replaced by the value of that variable.

Comment: It didn't work with the brackets, I got undefined :/

Comment: @Mit check the updated answer, it will work. initially it will return undefined but once you get the response it will return the proper value. to avoid the initial undefined put the check on userColors if it is blank `{}` then don't use the value.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use `this.state = ...` anywhere except in a class constructor. Instead use `this.setState({usersColors: {myObj: foo, etc: bar}})` One caveat: don't use `this.setState` in the `render()` method, you will just get an error.

Answer (score 1):

How to map the different html elements who are going to be the part of the same array object to the object in the components state. Like if i have following two html elements who are part of a single object user

```
<div className="form-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="user[username]"
          value={this.state.user.username}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder="Customer Name"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          name="user[mobilenumber]"
          value={this.state.user.mobilenumber}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder="Customer mbole no."
        />
      </div>
```

What should i give the name to these two elements such that they get mapped to the user object in the state present in the constructor

```
this.state = {
 user: { username: "", mobilenumber: "" },
 clothname: "",
 description: "",
 errors: {}
 };
```

ANd with the following simple onChange function

```
onChange(event) {
 this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```